# Modern theories of Russian syntax

Tags: syntax, russian

Western linguistics seems to be dominated by the Chomskian transformational generative grammar and its offshoots. My attempts to familiarize myself with these theories however always leave me under the impression that they were designed "by English speakers for description of their native English" - that is they might be not optimal for describing Russian. (Although this may be more due to the fact that the books/reviews are written for the English-speaking audience.)

I will appreciate comments on this subject. More specifically:

- Are transformational generative syntax theories popular among Russian linguists?
- Do these theories encounter specific problems when treating Russian and related languages? What kind of problems?
- What are the alternative theories? Are there any created by Russian-speaking linguists (or native speakers of Slavic languages)?

Comment: I've heard that [Tartu School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartu%E2%80%93Moscow_Semiotic_School) is pretty big, is it relevant to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it is worth looking into, although at the first glance it seems to be more about culture than syntax.

Comment: I just don't really understand the scope of generative syntax theories, they seem to tackle "why" question, which overlaps culture.

Comment: They overlap with the culture in the sense that they are the opposite to the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis, which suggests that language and culture are interrelated, whereas the generative syntax claims some universal (i.e. culture independent) syntax rules. They are also intertwined with biology, since our syntactic abilities should be innate.

However my question is more narrow: it is about syntax trees, substitution rules, X-bar theory, etc.

Comment: @shabunc The question is addressed specifically to Russian speakers. I think that migrating it to linguistics is inappropriate, since there I will get precisely the answers that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: it's a question about linguistics though (three different questions to be precise) - you've specifically stated that you are interested in  - it's enough for linguists community to figure out what can be and what can not be an answer.

Comment: I have also provided the context, indicating that the problem was specifically related to the different views that Russian-speaking linguists may hold, as opposed to the native English speakers.

Comment: a question to Russian-speaking linguists about linguistics is still a question on linguistics

Comment: Are you saying that in linguistics, unlike in other disciplines, Russia does not have its own authentic research schools/traditions?!

Comment: I never claimed such thing - still a language about linguistics is a question about linguistics. If, for instance, I ask about Russian school of math thought that would be a question about math history. This one is about linguistics.

Comment: When they talk in physics about "Landau school", "Feynmann school", "Fermi school", etc. it is definitely not about biography. Same in economics: "Chicago school" and "Austrian school" are definitely not about geography.

Btw, it reminds me that in Russia "establishing a new school of research" used to be among the criteria for obtaining a Doctoral degree (aka "доктор наук").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sebastian Shaumyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_Shaumyan) proposed an order-free theory of syntax which has some currency in the U.S. However, I don't know whether Shaumyan's work was the historical source of the Western versions. I heard him lecture at the 1969 Linguistic Summer Institute at Ohio State.  I think he wrote in Russian, though he was Armenian.  A version of the order-free theory was made part of the [*GPSG*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_phrase_structure_grammar) theory from the '80s, where the idea was formalized by giving phrase structure rules in sets having right-hand sides with symbols occurring in all possible orders.  There were ordering rules eliminating those rules specifying orders inconsistent with the facts of a given language.

This idea could be integrated into TG grammar easily enough, if someone wanted to do that, since the base component of a TG is a phrase structure grammar.

I should also mention the Russian linguist [N. S. Trubetzkoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Trubetzkoy) whose work was very influential in the early development of generative phonology.